# php array_combine() use in foreach

Tags: php

How can I use `array_combine()` in `foreach() for insert user in database?

I know other methods. But this time I wanted to do it in a very complicated way, but unfortunately I got an error.

The output is a warning.

Please help me and you do not have to write the code like this. Make two arrays yourself and work on them.

```
// under output ->  var_dump($stmt) 
// object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(126) "INSERT INTO users(username, email, 
// password, permission, created_at) VALUES (:username, :email, :password, :permission, now())" }


$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . "(" . implode(", ", $fields) . ", created_at) VALUES (:" . implode(", :", $fields) . ", now())";
// some code
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sqlInsert);
foreach (array_combine($fields, $values) as $field => $value) {
    $stmt->bindParam(":$field", $value);
}
$stmt->execute();
// some code
```

thank you very much

Comment: im not sure why you'd want to complicate it. just simply use question mark placeholders to build the statement using str repeat and load values in the execute method

Answer (score 0):

under code is true ...

````
    ```
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sqlInsert);
    $stmt->execute(array_combine($fields, $values));
    ```
````

but this is easy